# Pandas script doesnt work properly inside function but works fine if used step by step on jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this script which i have tested on about 20 separate dataframes now and it works fine when i execute the commands one by one but throws the Error: KeyError: "['to_drop'] not found in axis"  when run inside a single function in a for loop. Is it some execution order issue with pandas? or perhaps how it uses memory.? I have tested on the first few iters of a for loop and it works fine inside jupyter notebooks.

```
def calc_df(co):
try:
    dfbs = pd.read_csv(f"NSE/BS/NonFinancial/{co}_stnd_BS.csv")
    dfpl = pd.read_csv(f"NSE/PL/NonFinancial/{co}_stnd_PL.csv")
    if len(dfbs.columns) == 8 and len(dfpl.columns) == 8:
        dfbs.drop(['Unnamed: 0', '6'],axis=1, inplace=True)
        dfpl.drop(['Unnamed: 0', '6'],axis=1, inplace=True)

        dfbs.set_index('0')
        dfpl.set_index('0')

        dfbs.columns = dfbs.iloc[0]
        dfpl.columns = dfpl.iloc[0]

        dfbs = dfbs.transpose()
        dfpl = dfpl.transpose()

        dfbs.columns = dfbs.columns.fillna('to_drop')
        dfbs.drop('to_drop', axis=1, inplace=True)

        dfpl.columns = dfpl.columns.fillna('to_drop')
        dfpl.drop('to_drop', axis=1, inplace=True)


        cd = dfbs.filter(regex=("Balance Sheet"),axis=1)
        dfbs.drop(cd, axis=1, inplace=True)

        cd2 = dfpl.filter(regex=("Profit & Loss"), axis=1)
        dfpl.drop(cd2,axis=1, inplace=True)

        dfbs.replace(to_replace='--', value=0, inplace=True)
        dfpl.replace(to_replace='--', value=0, inplace=True)

        dfbs.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        dfpl.fillna(0, inplace=True)

        indx = dfpl.index.name
        df = dfbs.join(dfpl, rsuffix="_pl")

        for d in df.columns:
            df[d] = df[d].astype(float)



        df.to_csv(f'Cleaned/NSE/PL_BS/{co}_plbs.csv')
        dfbs.to_csv(f'Cleaned/NSE/BS/{co}_BS.csv')
        dfpl.to_csv(f'Cleaned/NSE/PL/{co}_PL.csv')
        print(f'data saved for {co}')
    else:
        print(f'inconsistent data for {co}')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f'file not found for {co}')
```

Comment: the two lines with `set_index`, you need to add the parameter `inplace=True` as you don't reassign